# Multiple .bash_profiles on mac osx

Tags: mongodb, bash, macos, conda

I'm taking a course on mongodb where I have to install the mongo shell on my mac. In order to run the mongo shell, I had to change the PATH in .bash_profile. The thing is I had anaconda installed and the bash profile for conda (which I overwrote for the mongo shell). So now, my conda prompt is not usable. I created a local conda environment where I can install some python dependencies I need, but for some reason, I can't execute conda commands in the folder I created the local environment for. I keep getting a 'command not found' response. I know for sure the conda environment was activated because its listed in my anaconda navigator.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider using [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) -- have one `shell.nix` per project describing the dependencies you want it to install, and then you have exactly the software you need for whatever you're currently working on. (Nix installs all software under its own, hash-addressed prefix, and then assembles a `PATH` with only the things you want at any given time).

Comment: ...beyond that, though -- instead of a paragraph of text without any precise technical details, how about providing code that someone else can run to produce your problem themselves? (That might be `.bashrc` content, conda steps, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i guess macos doesn’t have `.bashrc` cuz every shell in macos is treated as a login shell.

Comment: Sure. My point is that the OP should show us what they actually changed, not asking for `.bashrc` specifically. (And to be just a bit pedantic, not *every* shell is a login shell on MacOS; there are still noninteractive shells, and new interactive shells started in existing windows or tabs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that’s absolutely right, he should include some more info. Also I mentioned “i guess” cuz i wasn’t sure.

Comment: Apologies, so I can add pictures if need be but my question really is: Can I run conda commands like 'jupyter notebook' or 'pip' on a mongo shell? The answer seems like it's a NO. But the course I'm taking had me set up bash profile to a mongo PATH. The course also had us download Anaconda after this (which I didn't do because I already had it downloaded). If I had downloaded it AFTER, would it have rewritten the bash_profile to a conda setup? If yes, than this solves my problem, but also raises another one - what was the point of creating a bash profile for mongo in the first place.

Comment: pictures? Please don't post screenshots unless they are necessary. Copy/paste _text_ whenever possible.